# Passing "who" content into function Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, function, vector

I wish to pass the vectors recognised by "***who***" into a function. However, ***who*** produces a vector of strings where each string represents a vector. For example:

```
a=[1;0;0;0]
b=[0;1;0;0]
c=[0;0;0;1]   

CC = who
    CC = 

'a'
'b'
'c'
```

How do I get it into the form `xOut = f(a,b,c)` by using `CC` when `CC` can vary in length?
`f` takes the form:

```
function y = f(varargin)
y = any([varargin{:}], 2);
```

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without using `eval`, which is a strong code smell and has a significant negative impact on performance. If your function is expecting specific inputs, can you not just pass them explicitly? Or perhaps use a [structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) or [cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) array that your function can unpack?

Comment: My main problem is that CC varies in length, otherwise, yes, I could pass them explicitly with or without `eval`.

Comment: If it varies in length, what is `f` doing to handle it? A more specific example of your use case would be helpful to determine the proper solution.

Comment: I have now placed the function `f` in the question.

Comment: How does a,b,c ... etc. get generated?  In your previous question it said something about a "parent function".  Can you modify the parent to return the output into a cell array instead of separate vars or maybe a structure?  Ex. Parent function returns "out"  where out is a nx1 cell array out{1} = a, out{2} = b, out{3} = c ...     OR  as a struct  out.a, out.b, out.c ...   If you can do either of those then you don't need `who`

Comment: @AeroEngy "If you can do either of those" - Mary definitely should be able to do either of those, as they are the *correct* methodologies for this kind of situation. Don't use unknown amounts of variables, you'll only get into trouble, use structs and cell arrays instead!

Comment: @Wolfie  I agree 100%.  I only used the word "if"  because unfortunately sometimes in a tight SCM environment you aren't allowed to change something or it is exceeding difficult to get permission ... which is the world I live in :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think I can put `a`, `b`, and `c` directly into an array. So, putting `x(:,k)=eval(CC{k});` into a for loop and passing `x` into `f` is the "best" solution so far?

Comment: @Mary  You could do that and it would probably work  but I would look into doing it another way.    Using `eval` is usually a sign you have arranged your code poorly.  Also, since you are querying the current workspace are you sure there aren't other vars floating around that might be included and open you up for more errors.  I think with more information about what makes a, b, c, etc. that there is a better solution.  Restructuring the parent, using nargout to determine output size of parent, etc.

Comment: If variables are generated by loading a saved workspace, you could use `CC = load(...);`, which would assign variables in the saved workspace to fields in the structure `CC`. This could then be unpacked as a cell array. Likewise, you could first save the current workspace, then load it again.